# I'm building an online snippet management website, is there a control that I can use to visualize code and color code source according language?

Tags: php, zend-framework, user-controls

You guys know in Pastebin how according to the selected language, the code is colored?

Is there a control I can use on my site? I'm using PHP and Zend Framework.

Edit:
I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
CodeControl mycontrol = new CodeControl(sourcecode.txt, 'c#');
```

or

```
CodeControl mycontrol = new CodeControl(sourcecode.txt, 'javascript');
```

I'm sure someone already has done this, no point in reinventing the wheel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's **[highlight_string](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_misc_highlight_string.asp)** function for that. You can also use [**Prettify**](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) the code colorizer that StackOverflow uses.

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin function - highlight_string() but it only really deals with PHP source. You might want to try [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) which supports lots of langs.

C.